# Change the order of asp:GridView *autogenerated* columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, .net-4.0

First let me say that I've seen similar questions on StackOverflow, but none that I've seen deal specifically with auto-generated columns.

I have a `asp:GridView` that I am binding to an `IEnumerable<Data>`, where `Data` can vary depending on runtime input.  However, each `Data` class shares a couple base properties:

```
public class BaseData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AddressData : BaseData
{
    public string Street1 { get; set; }
    public string Street2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; };
}

public class ContactData : BaseData
{
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    // tons more public properties...
}

// More classes with lots of different public properties...
```

These different classes are populated by a database query, so I want to auto-generate columns when I place the data in the GridView because of the large number of different fields.  However, I want to display the columns that are in the shared base class first.  If I just assign the `IEnumerable<Data>` to the GridView datasource, the base classes properties are added last to the GridView's columns.  I tried remedying the situation like this:

```
// Callback after getting data from database
public void SetGridView<Data>(IEnumerable<Data> rows) where Data : BaseData
{
    // Make sure these columns show up first
    BoundField ID = new BoundField() { HeaderText = "ID", DataField = "ID" };
    BoundField Name = new BoundField() { HeaderText = "Name", DataField = "Name" };
    myGridView.Columns.Clear();
    myGridView.Columns.Add(ID);
    myGridView.Columns.Add(Name);
    myGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    myGridView.DataSource = rows;
    myGridView.DataBind();
}
```

However, this just duplicates the columns at the beginning and end, so the header looks like this:

```
ID    Name    Street1    Street2    City    State    ZipCode    ID    Name
```

So is there a way for me to move the columns that I know will be there (base class) to the beginning of the GridView's columns while still having the convenience of auto-generating all the other columns?

Comment: I think the call of SetGridView is too late in the page lifecycle (viewstate + control tree). Maybe you should looking into that.

Comment: I don't think it would be, as generated columns are only created when the data is available, and adding the bound fields does work, it just doesn't keep the auto-generation process from generating the same columns a second time.  Am I misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: Have you tried changing your Query to the order you want the columns to appear?

Comment: Yes, the query is already in the order that I want.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are forced to use auto-generated columns, I'd just create an intermediate `DataTable` to bind the GridView to.  In that `DataTable` object, you can add your columns in the order you prefer.  The GridView should then bind in that same order.

**Edit**:
Modify `BaseData`, add the following:

```
private DataTable dataForDisplay;

// This would be overridden by all child classes, adding their columns in the order you want
public virtual DataTable GetDataForDisplay()
{
    dataForDisplay = new DataTable();
    dataForDisplay.Columns.Add("ID");
    dataForDisplay.Columns.Add("Name");
    // If you want to change the order, just don't call the base.GetDataForDisplay()

    dataForDisplay.Rows.AddRange(this.ID, this.Name);

    return dataForDisplay;
}
```

Then all of the other child classes will override `GetDataForDisplay()`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know which columns to add until runtime and I would rather not have to set a gazillion fields in the DataTable and test for each possible Data subclass to know which fields to set.  AutoGenerateColumns is saving a lot of time and effort, I just need the two columns that I know will be present in all cases to be at the front instead of the back of the column collection.

Comment: But you do know the columns, because they're declared in the custom class.  You can include a `ConvertToDataTable()` method in each of your custom classes.  You can even make it part of the base class, call the base implementation, and then add the custom columns that match your custom class' properties.

Comment: I'm aware of that option, it will just mean a lot of work, and seems unnecessary.  I'd be essentially copying the contents of each class into a new data structure that specifies the fields in the order I want.  I don't understand why that kind of time, effort, and wasted memory should be necessary when all I want to do is change the order of an existing structure.

Comment: Well, when you do things "automagically" you relinquish a lot of your control.  If you want control over the order of the automatically-created columns, you need to provide the order in the underlying dataset, or create a separate GridView for each of the orders you want, then decide at runtime which GridView to bind to and display.